# Thermodynamic free energy of interacting system

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, partition-function

This question concerns an interacting system's thermodynamic free energy $\Omega$. Generally speaking, The action $S$ for an interacting system has the following form:

\begin{equation}
S(\phi,\psi) = S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)
\end{equation}
Where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are two generic fields.

The thermodynamic potential of the system is then given by
$$\Omega = -T \ln Z$$
Where the partition function is given by
$$ Z = \int d\phi d\psi ~e^{-\beta S(\phi,\psi)} = \int d\phi d\psi ~e^{-\beta \Bigl(S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)\Bigr)}  $$

The problem is to evaluate the integral
$$ \Omega = -T \ln~ \left( \int d\phi d\psi ~e^{-\beta \Bigl(S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)\Bigr)} \right) $$

In general, it is quite hard to evaluate the above integral. Landau invented a trick to evaluate this, which has been discussed in his [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Statistical_Physics.html?id=VzgJN-XPTRsC). Later [AGD](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Methods_of_Quantum_Field_Theory_in_Stati/Qgb_vgEACAAJ?hl=en) extended Landau's work in field theory. There exists a whole simulation industry dedicated to evaluating this integral numerically. The way I understand the problem goes as follows:

Let's first introduce a dimensionless "adiabatic parameter" $\lambda$, such that when $\lambda = 0$, the system is "free," and we know how to evaluate $\Omega$. Now, when $\lambda = 1$, the system is fully interacting, and we are interested to know the corresponding $\Omega$. This suggests that the change in $\Omega$ can be written as:
$$ \Delta\Omega = \int_{0}^{1} d\lambda \frac{\partial\Omega(\lambda)}{\partial\lambda} $$

In terms of $\lambda$ the $Z$ can be written as

$$ Z(\lambda) = \int d\phi d\psi ~e^{-\beta S(\lambda;\phi,\psi)} = \int d\phi d\psi ~e^{-\beta \Bigl(S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + \lambda S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)\Bigr)}  $$

Then
$$ \Delta\Omega = -T\int_{0}^{1} d\lambda ~ \frac{1}{Z(\lambda)} \frac{\partial Z(\lambda)}{\partial\lambda} $$

Then
$$ \Delta\Omega = T\int_{0}^{1} d\lambda ~ \frac{1}{Z(\lambda)} \left[\int d\phi d\psi~ S_{\mathrm{int}}(\psi,\phi) e^{-\beta \Bigl(S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + \lambda S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)\Bigr)} \right] $$

Which can be written as

$$ \Delta\Omega = T\int_{0}^{1} d\lambda ~ \frac{\langle S_{\mathrm{int}}(\psi,\psi)\rangle_{\lambda}}{Z(\lambda)}  $$
Where,
$$ \langle S_{\mathrm{int}}(\psi,\psi)\rangle_{\lambda} = \int d\phi d\psi~ S_{\mathrm{int}}(\psi,\phi) e^{-\beta \Bigl(S_{\mathrm{free}}(\phi) + S_{\mathrm{free}}(\psi) + \lambda S_{\mathrm{int}}(\phi,\psi)\Bigr)}  $$

We have been able to get rid of the log with the price of introducing the integration over $\lambda$! A further complication arises since both the numerator and the denominator of $\Delta\Omega$ depend on $\lambda$. To my knowledge, a variant of the above expression was first given by [John G. Kirkwood](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jcp/article-abstract/3/5/300/203696/Statistical-Mechanics-of-Fluid-Mixtures?redirectedFrom=fulltext).

**Question:** The way one can evaluate this expression is to evaluate the averages of interaction terms for different orders in $\lambda$. Then, pull the denominator up, expand it to a power series in $\lambda$, and simplify and integrate over $\lambda$ at the end. Does this proposition sound reasonable? Hopefully, PSE people can inject their input.

Comment: For reformulation of AGD in terms of path integrals, you may check [Negelé&Orland](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.1201/9780429497926/quantum-many-particle-systems-john-negele)